# How to improve detection of sentences in Sphinx?

Tags: full-text-search, sphinx, full-text-indexing

It is possible to search words in one sentence with Sphinx. For example, we have next text:

> Вася молодец, съел огурец, т.к. проголодался. Такие дела.

If I search

```
молодец SENTENCE огурец
```

i find this text. If I search

```
молодец SENTENCE проголодался
```

I cant find this text, because dot from phrase `т.к.` regarded as end of sentence.

And how I see, set of delimiters is hardcoded in [Sphinx's sources](https://github.com/sphinxsearch/sphinx/blob/master/src/sphinx.cpp#L3967).

My question is how to improve detection of sentence? Better way for me is to use Yandex's Tomita parser or another nlp library with smart detection of sentences.

Comment: YEs, its hardcoded, but the rules around '.' should be setup such that `T.K.` shouldnt be considered a sentance boundary, as its an abriviation. http://sphinxsearch.com/docs/current.html#conf-index-sp  -

Comment: @barryhunter, yes, but `т.к.` is not standard abbreviation for Sphinx? How to specify this abbreviation? Any way possible other situations: "Компании Yahoo! известна во всем мире." and other cases. I think what better way - to delegate segmentation to external library...

Comment: thats the thing according to rules, it should be counted as abrivation (as I understand it), its rule based rather than specific appriviations. As extending sphinx to use more extensive rules, would need to modify the source.

Comment: @barryhunter, as I see, exists another problem with abbreviations: "Вот и пришла осень в U.S.A. В лесу медведи жуют ягоды.". Sphinx these two sentences glues into one...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Split text into sentences with Yandex's Tomita parser. We get the text, which splited by "\n".

Delete all ".", "!", "?" leaving last from each sentence.

Build the Sphinx index with this preprocessed data.